# When open new window,the ieDriverServer can not be closed

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, automated-tests, iedriverserver

```
@AfterClass
public void aClass(){
    LogUtil.info("-------Finished Test Class-----------");
    if (action != null)
        action.tearDown("-------Finished Test Class-----------");
    }
```

and the tearDown(String ) is below:

```
public void tearDown(){
    try{
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.quit();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }
    }
```

now I find that when there is a operation to open url in new window
then after that ,the ieDriverServer always can not be closed on the step

"driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()"

but if there is no operation to open url in new window ,the ieDriverServer can be delete cookies and quit normally

PS:
my env is below:
Windows 7  64bits

IE 11 latest
ieDriverServer the latest 32bits

Comment: please note that only when open url in new window that this issue occurs

Comment: How can you `there is a operation to open url in new window` when you have already `driver.quit()`. How are you trying to open a new url? how can `ieDriverServer always can not be closed on the step` through `"driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()"`?